# JSF 1.2 Datatable attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I want to use rowstyleclass instead of rowclasses in datatable.
Can we use rowstyleclass attribute of datatable in JSF 1.2?

Actually,depending on condition i want the color of the row to be displayed in JSF 1.2  datatable.

any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

Based on [JSF 1.2 TLD](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/) documentation `h:dataTable` has **rowClasses** attribute and doesn't have rowstyleclass attribute.